# error while calling to $modal service from run block

Tags: angularjs

In my main module i have used ui-bootstrap modal for checking login authentication.From run block i have called to loginModal service but it is giving Error

> TypeError: loginModal is not a function

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ui.router', 'ui.bootstrap', 'loginServices','leaveServices']). config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');
        $stateProvider.
            state('home', {
                url:'/home',
                data: {
                    requireLogin: false
                },
                views: {
                    '': {
                        templateUrl: 'partials/templates/assets/home.html'
                    }
                }
            }).
            state('home.about', {
                url: '/about',
                templateUrl: 'partials/templates/assets/about.html'
            }).
            state('home.contact', {
                url: '/contact',
                templateUrl: 'partials/templates/assets/contactUs.html'
            }).
            state('/login', {
                url: '/login',
                data: {
                    requireLogin: false
                },
                templateUrl: 'partials/login.html',
                controller: loginUserController
            }).
            state('/register', {
                url:'/register',
                data: {
                    requireLogin: false
                },
                templateUrl: 'partials/registerUser.html',
                controller: registerController
            }).
            state('/getAllUsers', {
                url: '/getAllUsers',
                data: {
                    requireLogin: false
                },
                templateUrl: 'partials/getAllUsers.html',
                controller: getUsersController
            }).
            state('/updateUser', {
                url : '/updateUser/:id/:name',
                data: {
                    requireLogin: true
                },
                params: {'id':null, 'name':null},
                templateUrl: 'partials/updateUser.html',
                controller: updateUserController
            }).
            state('/userLeave', {
                url : '/userLeave:name',
                data: {
                    requireLogin: true
                },
                params: {'name': null},
                templateUrl: 'partials/userLeave.html',
                controller: userLeaveController
            }).
            state('/leaveRequest', {
                url : '/leaveRequest',
                data: {
                    requireLogin: true
                },
                templateUrl: 'partials/leaveRequest.html'
            });
    }])

    .run(function ($rootScope, $state, loginModal) {
    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function (event, toState, toParams) {
        var requireLogin = toState.data.requireLogin;
        console.log('going to state '+toState.name);
        if (requireLogin && typeof $rootScope.currentUser === 'undefined') {
            event.preventDefault();

            loginModal().then(function () {
                    return $state.go(toState.name, toParams);
                })
                .catch(function () {
                    return $state.go('/login');
                });
        }
    });
})
.factory('loginModal', function ($modal, $rootScope) {

    function assignCurrentUser (user) {
        $rootScope.currentUser = user;
        return user;
    }

    return function() {
            var instance = $modal.open({
                templateUrl: 'partials/login.html',
                controller: loginUserController
            });

            return instance.result.then(assignCurrentUser);
        }
});
```

---

here login controller

```
loginUserController.$inject = ['$scope','$http', 'loginFactory', '$location', '$state'];
function loginUserController($scope,$http,loginFactory,$location, $state){

$scope.validateLogin = function(name,password){
    $http.get("http://localhost:3010/validateLogin?userName="+name+"&password="+password)
        .then(function(response) {
            if(response.data.length != 0) {
                console.log("logged user data is "+JSON.stringify(response.data));
                $state.transitionTo('/userLeave', {name: name});
           //     $scope.$close(response);
            }
            else
                $scope.inValidUser = 'Invalid User';
        });
};
$scope.cancel = $scope.$dismiss;
}
```

Comment: error is : TypeError: loginModal is not a function
    at app.module.js:87

Comment: Do you have any other errors in your console? What versions of Angular and ui-bootstrap are you using?

Comment: script(src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.4/angular.min.js')
        script(src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.4/angular-resource.min.js')
        script(src='http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.min.js')
        script(src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js')
        script(src='//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js')

Comment: https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/2.4.0/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js

Answer (score 0):

Could be because you're using an Angular [service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/auto/service/$provide#service) which expects a constructor which in turn, should **not** be returning something.

Try changing to a [factory](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/auto/service/$provide#factory), eg

```
.factory('loginModal', ...
```

Comment: TypeError: loginModal.get(...).then(...).catch is not a function

Comment: @SushilWaykar why did you change your code to include `.get()`? You shouldn't have had to change anything else. It should still be `loginModal().then(...)`

Comment: This *looks* more like a DI issue rather than a service vs factory issue.  I don't see anywhere where the `loginModal` service is being injected.

Comment: angular.min.js:63 TypeError: loginModal(...).then(...).catch is not a function

Comment: @makoto the error message would be different if it was an injection issue

Comment: @SushilWaykar that's very odd. Your error message seems to indicate that `loginModal().then(...)` does not return a promise

Comment: @Makoto the `loginModal` service is injected in the module's `run` method

Comment: i have taken this example from below given link:

Comment: http://brewhouse.io/blog/2014/12/09/authentication-made-simple-in-single-page-angularjs-applications.html